# Setup Unity for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I am new bee in unity, and working on an app which will be use for both iPhone and iPad. I build this and install on device its by default for iPhone, i don't know how and where to enable this for iPad also like in xcode setting we change to universal app. Sorry for silly question but i am blind in unity please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top (the toolbar) Click on File then Build Settings. When you have done that, then go to the button of the new window and click on Player settings. Then you have done that should the inspector window change and show you different things you can change, under configuration tab there is a target Target device setting. Set it to Ipad/Iphone.